# Click event only fireing once

Tags: jquery

I want it to fire every time i click

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gorelegacy/Kd3aN/)

my jquery

```
$(function(){

var list = $("ul li").toArray();
var elemlength = list.length;
var randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*elemlength);
var randomitem = list[randomnum];
$("#button").bind('click', function(e){
$(randomitem).addClass("lunch");
});
```

});

Comment: The event is fired every time in you fiddle, what do you want to do?

Comment: The event fires every time – but you _see_ nothing different, because you determined `randomitem` only once before, and it _stays_ what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the random item in the click handler

```
$(function () {

    $("#button").bind('click', function (e) {
        var list = $("ul li:not(.lunch)");
        $("ul li.lunch").removeClass('lunch')
        var elemlength = list.length;
        var randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * elemlength);
        list.eq(randomnum).addClass("lunch");
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nkEdb/)

Comment: Cheers. What would i do so it replaces the previous action...not keeping on appending down?

Answer (score 0):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/JVq9S/

To start with:

- Scope of your `randomnum` and `randomitem` were wrong.

rest should help the need `:)`

**sample code**

```
$(function () {

    var list = $("ul li").toArray();
    var elemlength = list.length;


    $("#button").on('click', function (e) {
          var randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * elemlength);
            var randomitem = list[randomnum];

        $(randomitem).addClass("lunch");
    });

});
```